# why the id of thread changed

Tags: android, multithreading

i don't understand why i get different Id for the same thread here is the output 

 i know the id field  in any programming language must stay the same for future reference 

 PS:this code is inside a bound service class i know the bound service is on the main thread but why  id of the "message thread" changed  3 times from -1 to 21947 to 41045

```
*logcat output:
    onCreate: thread id = 1 name =main
    first is alive true thread id -1 thread name =servicemessanger
    sec is alive true thread id 21947 thread name =servicemessanger
    handleMessage: thread id= 41045name = servicemessanger* 




code :
     @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: thread id = "+ Thread.currentThread().getId()+" name =" +Thread.currentThread().getName()  );
            super.onCreate();
            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("servicemessanger");
            thread.start();
            Log.i(TAG, " first is alive "+thread.isAlive() + " thread id "+ thread.getThreadId()+ " thread name ="+thread.getName());
            mHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper()){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    Log.i(TAG, "handleMessage: thread id= "+Thread.currentThread().getId()+"name = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            };
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            Log.i(TAG, " sec is alive "+thread.isAlive() + " thread id "+ thread.getThreadId()+ " thread name ="+thread.getName());

        }
```

thank you,

Comment: post your logcat then

Comment: `onCreate: thread id = 1 name =main` this is main ui thread

Comment: logcat output:---->
 -   onCreate: thread id = 1 name =main
   - first is alive true thread id -1 thread name =servicemessanger
  -  sec is alive true thread id 21947 thread name =servicemessanger
  -  handleMessage: thread id= 41045name = servicemessanger

Comment: then you are using `thread.getThreadId()` see: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java#162

Comment: yes but every time i ask abut  messagethread id with  thread.getThreadId() command  i get different result

Comment: no, you can get either -1 or some other value, see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java#162

Comment: here is the thread HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("servicemessanger");

Comment: ok what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: i'm trying to get the id of variable called thread  that i instantiate but everytime i try i get different ID this is my first time using HandlerThread
i don't know why the ID is change every time i use getThreadId() function 
 there must be a reason but i can't figure it out

Comment: thank you ahh is see it know is modified in the run code  mTid = Process.myTid(); 
i think  mTid is the linux thread ID
and if i use .getId() methode i'll get the actual id
thank you very much :) you helped me lot